# Broken Debian package with Quickly due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: application-development, packaging, quickly

I created a test application with Quickly. When I used `quickly package`, I get this warning:

```
Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
...............................................................................................................................................................................
Befehl gab einige WARNUNGEN zurück:
----------------------------------
** (setup.py:3685): WARNING **: Fehler beim Senden der Anmeldedaten: Fehler beim Senden der Nachricht: Die Operation ist nicht erlaubt
----------------------------------
```

If I try to install the .deb, I get this warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1041, in _simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self.__simulate(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1098, in __simulate
    deb = self.install_file(trans, simulate=True, **trans.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 591, in install_file
    deb = self._check_deb_file(path, force, trans.uid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1227, in _check_deb_file
    "\n%s" % (path, stdout))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Running `debuild` instead of `quickly` package gave this output: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1052328/

Comment: Could you point us to your code (e.g. in a Launchpad branch) so that we can have a look at it to be able to help? Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a problem with the syntax. You have probably used python 3.2 syntax instead of 2.7

Comment: I doesent changed anything i just tried to package the example project.

Comment: if i install it with "sudo dpkg -i"
everything works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you see an error such as this it means that a non-English character cannot be displayed - this is a common problem when you have people translate your application and non-English characters need to be displayed.

My workaround for this is usually to convert the string to UTF-8 before it is displayed. Example:

```
str = widget.get_text(label).decode("UTF-8")
```

(note: I haven't tested this code, but usually adding `decode()` to a string works).